# python trying to remove single apostrophe

Tags: python, printing, apostrophe

I'm using a program called CityEngine which has a python element to it.

The problem: I've just called a function on an object and returns me a list of numbers, xyz. I split the xyz into their own names.  I also call a function to retrieve a different attribute related to this object to replace the previously retrieved y value.

Now, when I print the y value, it contains numerical characters only apart from decimal place.
When I incorporate the y value into a new list, it's value has single apostrophe around it.

For example, print(y) returns 5.0000000

If I place it like this position[x,y,z] I get a print(position) of [0, '5.000000' , 0]. The program can't read the single apostrophes so ignored the value completely.

I've tried .remove("'","") and .strip() and nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks more as if the function were not returning a number but a string. So, in order to deal with it, you’ll have to convert the string using either `int()` or `float()`.

In general, if you do a `print(l)` on some list of items, each item will be printed with the output of it’s `__repr__` method. Convention has it that the `__repr__` method of string wraps the string with single apostrophes, whereas numbers do not get wrapped. This is to remove potential ambiguity. Hence, a `print(l)` which returned

```
[0, '5.00000', 0.1]
```

would be a list containing an `int`, a `str` and a `float`.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, solved the problem. Will accept answer in 5 minutes :) . For anyone just starting out in python as I am, the way to convert, in my case y = float(y)

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to float ... It is a string, so you need to do string to float conversion